# Scraping into different pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

Im trying  to scrap a web page, and after following some tutorials, i found how to scrap different products, and how to change the page, but not at the same time. I tryed some ways to do it, but couln't find out.

This is my scraping code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const xlsx = require("xlsx");

async function getPageData(url,page){
  await page.goto(url);


const h1 = await page.$eval(".product_main h1", h1 => h1.textContent);
const price = await page.$eval(".price_color", price => price.textContent);
const instock = await page.$eval(".instock.availability", instock => instock.innerText);

return {
    title: h1,
    price: price,
    instock: instock
}


//await browser.close();
};

async function getLinks(){
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://books.toscrape.com/');
      
  const links = await page.$$eval('.product_pod .image_container a', allAs =>
  allAs.map(a => a.href));

  
}

async function main(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const data = await getPageData("https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html",page);
    console.log(data);
  
}

main();
```

And here is my code to change the page:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const xlsx = require("xlsx");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://books.toscrape.com/');
  
  while(await page.$(".pager .next a")){ 
    await page.click(".pager .next a"); 
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  }

})();
```

Comment: I don't know about puppeteer (I use CefSharp for scraping) but, maybe an option save data into localStorage to persists between navigations?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "change the page", exactly? BTW -- books.toscrape is a fully static site, last I checked, so Puppeteer (browser automation) is overkill. You can get all of the data with a simple HTTP request for the .html file, then use a lightweight HTML parser like Cheerio to extract whatever data you want. `waitForTimeout` is a poor/lazy substitute for `waitForNavigation` here, and finally, you're leaking `browser` memory multiple times. Always call `browser.close()`, and preferably only use 1 browser for all work.